# word counter Javascript function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wanted to have a word counter next to a input textbox on the website

Got it working to show the count when the user click or modify the text but I wanted to load up straight away when the page finish loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#product_name").change(displayText).keyup(displayText);

function displayText(){
      $("em#counter").text($(this).val().length +' chars'); 
}
});
```

So I tried this the code below but couldn't get it working and don't know why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if($("#product_name").length){
           displayText();
    }
  $("#product_name").change(displayText).keyup(displayText);

function displayText(){
      $("em#counter").text($(this).val().length +' chars'); 
}
});
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: We'll need more information to answer your question. Is it throwing an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if($("#product_name").length){
           displayText();
}
$("#product_name").change(displayText).keyup(displayText);

function displayText(){
      $("em#counter").text($("#product_name").val().length +' chars'); 
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/msPQE/2/)

Problem was your `displayText()` call during page load. In `displayText` you had used `$(this)` to access the input field, which was working as a event handler. But when you call `displayText` directly `this` will point to the window object.

Answer (score 0):

Try .on() with multiple event.

```
$("#product_name").on({
    change: function() {
        // Handle change event
    },
    keyup: function() {
        // Handle keyup
    }
});
```

and for "when the page finish loading." use `$(window).load(function() { });`